# Agenda for Tuesday's chat session

Tags: discussion, chat, chat-events

We have a chat session coming up next Tuesday at 16:00 UTC in the Physics chat room. Recent chats have been a bit amorphous, so if there are any issues you want to raise now is a good time to crystallise your thoughts.

This is of course just an excuse for me to highlight the single most important burning issue of the moment: please, please, please can we rename the chat room to *Schrödinger's chat* :-)

### Update

There is clearly no enthusiasm for renaming the chat room. You may consider this suggestion abandoned.

I'll leave the question open here in case anyone wants to use it to suggest other topics for the chat session.

Comment: Well it is nice to have a meta post for the agenda...

Comment: I suppose if I'm soliciting opinions on the name change I should post an answer for people to up or downvote. I'll do this now.

Comment: Why change it?  The h bar is brilliant.

Comment: @JohnRennie Maybe we can change it for one week as David Z had suggested ? Looking at the votes it seems many people feel more comfortable sticking to "h bar" and don't want any permanent change to the name.

Answer (score 1):

In order to also have it here: We will likely discuss [Chat and the moderation thereof](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9596/50583) unless no one present is interested.

Answer (score -2):

In response to the renaming request: we *can* do it, but we also can't.

Comment: Are you certain about that?

Answer (score -3):

Please upvote this if you support the change of the chat room name to *Schrödinger's chat*.

Please downvote this if you disagree with the name change.

Comment: Chat name suggestions for voting goes here: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1028/2451